# Jenkins declarative pipeline parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to pass in a parameter to a Jenkinsfile from the organization folder instead of the job level or global level?

Essentially what I'm looking to do is have one Jenkinsfile that handles whatever situation I need, and have multiple organization folders that send it parameters. So basically I can have one organization folder that scans and grabs all of the feature branches, and when I run one of the jobs it merges them to develop. Another one that grabs all of the develop branches, and when I run one of the jobs it just builds them. etc.

I need some way to pass parameters to my Jenkinsfile to say "Hey I'm this folder, this is what you should do". I can't find a way to do so. I thought of making multiple Jenkinsfiles but it would be confusing to know which one to place in each repo. I would change the names of the Jenkinsfiles so it's obvious which one to use, but the only option I get for "Project Recognizer" in the configuration is "Pipeline Jenkinsfile" so I don't know how I can change the names and the organization folder still recognize it.

Is there something I'm missing? Any way to send a parameter to my Jenkinsfile from the folder instead of a global level? Or is there some other way to solve my problem and be able to tell my Jenkinsfile what to do depending on what organization folder it is in inside of Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there some other way to solve my problem and be able to tell my Jenkinsfile what to do depending on what organization folder it is in inside of Jenkins?

A simple way to check in which organization folder job is built is to parse it from `env.JOB_NAME` parameter. For example:

Jobs hierarchies:

```
feature/job1
feature/job2
production/job1
production/job2
```

To make Jenkins Pipeline to do different functionality whether they are in feature or production organization:

```
def topFolder = env.JOB_NAME.split('/')[0]

// In code somewhere else:
if (topFolder == 'feature') {
    doSomething()
} else if (topFolder == 'production') {
    doOther()
}
```